# ATTiny20 Stuck in Reset Loop after Watchdog Reset

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I am currently using an interrupt to reset an ATTiny20. Here is the relevant code:

```
int main(void)
{
    ...

    // Set up interrupt for reset button (PCINT5)
    SREG |= 1<<7;           // Enable global interrupts
    GIMSK |= 1<<PCIE0;      // Enable Pin Change Interrupt 0 (enables interrupts on PCINT[7:0]
    PCMSK0 |= 1<<PCINT5;    // Enable PCINT5 (physical pin 8) interrupt
    ...
}
```

The interrupt-handling function:

```
ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
    if (!(BUTTON_1_PORT & 1<<BUTTON_1_PIN))    // Only reset if button is pushed
    {   
        wdt_enable(WDTO_2S);
        while(1){};
    }
}
```

This works quite well - when the button is pushed the system freezes for 2 seconds and then resets... and promptly gets stuck in a reset loop. A bit of googling uncovered the culprit: on newer chips the watchdog timer is left enabled (at its shortest delay setting) after a watchdog reset. The following code is meant to remedy this issue:

```
// Disable watchdog on reset
void wdt_init(void) __attribute__((naked)) __attribute__((section(".init3")));
void wdt_init(void)
{
    // MCUSR = 0;    // See below for reason for commenting this line
    wdt_disable();
    return;
}
```

*N.B. `MCUSR = 0` is commented out because MCUSR does not exist on the ATTiny20. I have tried replacing it with `SREG = 0` but to no avail.

Even with this code in place, which should disable the watchdog timer, the issue persists. Flashing LEDs on the device indicate that the program is running through part of the `main()` function before it resets, but putting `wdt_disable();` at the top of `main()` has not helped either.

Is there something critical that I'm missing re: the ATTiny20? Something I've missed in the datasheet? The problem - and solution - seem so obvious, but I'm stumped. I'm using Atmel Studio 6.1.

Comment: Is the wdt_init absolutely getting called? What debugging capabilities do you have? Perhaps there is an interrupt that is fired when the watch dog is about to reset the chip... maybe there you can disable it?

Comment: @gcb unfortunately the ATTiny20 has no debugging capabilities. I did find the answer though, and have added it below. Just took a night's sleep and a morning coffee to notice this line in the datasheet: *WDE is overridden by WDRF in RSTFLR. This means that WDE is always set when WDRF is set. To clear WDE, WDRF
must be cleared first. This feature ensures multiple resets during conditions causing failure, and a safe start-up after the
failure.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Disable watchdog on reset
void wdt_init(void) __attribute__((naked)) __attribute__((section(".init3")));
void wdt_init(void)
{
    // This is the flag that must be cleared on an ATTiny20 before the WDT can be disabled
    /***************/
    /* RSTFLR = 0; */
    /***************?

    wdt_disable();
    return;
}
```

Comment: It's the same for me with an ATTiny10, there needs to be `RSTFLR = 0` before `wdt_disable()` in the special init3 section. Thanks!